# Java string as text variable

Tags: java, mysql, string

I am trying to insert a bit of text into my MYSQL database via java.

the variable I am trying to put it into is a TEXT variable. My problem is that when I try to insert it, it  picks up on the ' and thinks that it is a messed up insertion.

Here is the insert:

```
INSERT INTO TermsAndConditions (name,description,ownerID)  VALUES  ('bar condtions','Don't be stealin my stuff','2')
```

it thinks that by me having the word "Don't" is messed up

What I want to do is to do as little work as possible and tell the string just accept that all the characters need (their will probs be more than just the ' ) to have a "\'" or "\£" before them.

I know I can use replace but for ALL the characters would be a real pain! I am asking because their must be another simpler solution!

Thanks

Comment: Please add the Java code you use to execute this `INSERT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet will likely to be use prepared statements (which is a good idea on it's own if you're not controlling the input for the insert to avoid sql injection!)

This site provides an example of how to do it: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.sql/InsertPs.html

For your example, it would be something like:

```
// Prepare a statement to insert a record
String sql = "INSERT INTO TermsAndConditions (name,description,ownerID)  VALUES  (?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

// Set the values
pstmt.setString(1, "bar condtions");
pstmt.setString(2, "Don't be stealin my stuff");
pstmt.setString(3, "2");

// Insert the row
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I have used prepared statements before but didn't realise that they did this! I do not want to use them really as I know what I want to insert at this point so it really not needed and in fact less safe in the code I am writing. However, it works and should be fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the single quote or, better still, use prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to escape your special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using prepared statements? The problem here is a matter of escaping Strings properly. Prepared statements can handle that for you and reduce unclean and ugly concatonation code.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape the single quote like this:

```
INSERT INTO TermsAndConditions (name,description,ownerID)  VALUES  ('bar condtions','Don\'t be stealin my stuff','2')
```

Comment: That doesn't answer his question.  He is looking to use prepared strings to avoid worrying about escape sequences.

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma The OP said absolutely nothing about prepared statements.  I was simply pointing out why his insert was not working. Java and its various DB connection libraries provide any number of ways to achieve this.

Comment: I agree.  Originally I added such a solution as a comment.  But after re-reading he clearly states that he doesn't want to have to worry about adding "\" escape sequences.  Regardless, its a shame you got a down vote :(  That was not my doing.  I was just pointing out that this doesn't help his goal of the question.